# Why does this query show only one result?

Tags: php, sql, search, conditional-statements, sql-like

The query I have below will only show me one result even if there are multiple matching entries (completely or partially matching).  How do I fix it so it will return all matching entries:

```
//$allowed is a variable from database.

$sql = "SELECT `users`.`full_name`, `taglines`.`name`, `users`.`user_id` FROM 
`users`  LEFT JOIN `taglines` ON `users`.`user_id` = `taglines`.`person_id`
 WHERE ( `users`.`user_settings` = '$allowed' ) and ( `users`.`full_name` 
 LIKE '%$q%' ) LIMIT $startrow, 15";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($result == "")
{
    echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $person = htmlspecialchars($row['full_name']);
    }
}
}  

print $person;
```

Comment: might be because of the $startrow in the limit clause

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: @sarnold yes don't worry.  they are being sanitized.  according to an expert on stackoverflow it doesn't matter what i use, prepared or this way, risks are the same.

Comment: @sarnold btw if i individually sanitize vs using PDO, isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @Ariel: Roughly the same, yes, but with PDO you cannot screw it up and forget or double-sanitize a variable.

Comment: what happens if you double-sanitize a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your overwriting `$person` on each iteration.

Hold it in a `$person[]` array if your expecting more then one. Then loop through it with a foreach loop when you intend to output.

Not related but your also querying twice, you only need 1 `$result = mysql_query($sql);`

### Update (Simple Outputting Example):

```
<?php 
$person=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $person[] = array('full_name'=>$row['full_name'],
                   'email'=>$row['email'],
                   'somthing_else1'=>$row['some_other_column']);
}

//Then when you want to output:
foreach($person as $value){
    echo '<p>Name:'.htmlentities($value['full_name']).'</p>';
    echo '<p>Eamil:'.htmlentities($value['email']).'</p>';
    echo '<p>FooBar:'.htmlentities($value['somthing_else1']).'</p>';
}
?>
```

Or an alternative way to is to build your output within the loop using concatenation.

```
<?php 
$person='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $person .= '<p>Name:'.$row['full_name'].'</p>';
 $person .= '<p>Email:'.$row['email'].'</p>';
}

echo $person;
?>
```

Or just echo it.

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo '<p>Name:'.$row['full_name'].'</p>';
 echo '<p>Email:'.$row['email'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added the $person[] to the $person = htmlspecialchars($row['full_name']); but when i print it it says "array."

Comment: use `print_r($person)` to see the array contents.

Comment: OK.  i used print_r($person);die(); and that printed two entries like this: Array ( [0] => Jack Smith [1] => Jack Wilson ) and both of those are the only matching names so i know its right.  but now how do i make this work for my query as in the ability to use print $person; and then show all entries that return.

Comment: Ok, i used foreach ($person as $key => $value) echo "$value"; and was able to do it.

Comment: Thanks but say i don't want to echo them right after the while() and want to use them in another part of the page? i am unable to use the variables...

Comment: Looks like i was able to get it to work by using the foreach snippet wherever i need to do a echo in the script that uses those rows. Thanks Lawrence.